# Best practices to manage an indexable string list?

Tags: objective-c, ios, database-design, data-formats

Suppose I fetched a string (`0102030405`, in hex) from the web service, then I need to parse it to localized names. For example: `01` will be parsed to `name_1`, and `02` will be parsed to `name_2`, etc, if the preferred language is English.

I want to store a string list file like this:

```
name_1
name_2
name_3
...(hundreds of)
```

I don't want to compile it, and what's more, **it should be indexed**.
But how can I archive this? Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by indexed?  Like a search index?

Comment: @jsd ya, that's it. Sorry for my poor English :p It just like a `NSArray`, values can be get by `objectAtIndex:`.

Comment: Well, I'm reading about `.strings` & `plist`.. maybe they'll work..

Comment: I think a plist containing an array of strings will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found that `.plist` is really suitable!

#### Workaround:

Manually create a `stringList.plist` with `array` type, and while the app is first installed to the device, call a method to copy the plist file to `Documents` folder, so I can update it anytime without the requirement of updating the app.

Here're some links that help me a lot:

1. [Using iOS SDK to create a plist at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447341/using-ios-sdk-to-create-a-plist-at-runtime)
2. [Reading a plist into an NSArray](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/data-file-management/reading-a-plist-into-an-nsarray.html)
3. [Create Plist Programmatically](http://iphonesdevsdk.blogspot.com/2011/04/plist.html)

Thanks for the authors here. :)